# AngularJS not recognizing controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I already know when I see the answer I'm going to feel really dumb, but I'm working through the AngularJS tutorials at egghead.io. When I do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS Tutorials</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/foundation/stylesheets/foundation.min.css">
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    </body>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp">

            <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
                <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
                <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
            </div>

            <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
                <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
                <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>  
</html>
```

with my JavaScript file as so (named main.js):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('Data', function() {
    return { message: "I'm data from a service"}
})

function FirstCtrl($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
}

function SecondCtrl($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
}
```

My `{{ data.message }}` isn't recognized as an AngularJS binding (i.e. in the page it shows up as 

 `{{ data.message }}` instead of `"I'm data from a service"`). But if I take all the JS code and put it into `<script></script>` tags directly in the HTML it works fine. Am I missing a reference or something? Haven't seemed to find this anywhere, likely because it's really basic.

Comment: As I said...I feel D-U-M-B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to **JUMP THE GUN** and recommend you switch these

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

> If this works then that is because before you were trying to use angular when it wasn't event loaded.

---

> ## Tip
>
> ---
>
> Now, when I first started with javascript these sort of things used to happen to me a lot. The best thing for you to do is learn how to use the `console` it would have told you in the console something along the lines of `cannot read property 'module' of undefined` that meaning that `angular` is `undefined` and therefore not loaded.

Comment: Well, by virtue of speed, I'll accept yours...when it lets me...Yeah, realized I was being an idiot. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: That's a good point. Definitely haven't used the console as much as I should.

Comment: The console will solve all of your problems, if you don't understand the errors then copy and give to google, and he will have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Load Angular before your controllers, not after

Answer (score 1):

switch between the lines:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

you need to run main.js after angular is loaded